# get the location list based on the current location of the end user with gocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation, rails-geocoder

I am trying to find the locations that are nearest from the end user and the string

currently using the geocoder gem like following way

```
locations = Geocoder.search(search_location)
```

currently it gives me the locations that matched with the search_location..

what i want is like below........

give the current users latitude and longitude and find the nearest location based on the search_location.

I have already tries below

locations = Location.near([current_user.latitude, current_user.longitude], 50, :order => :distance)

Answer (score 1):

Geocoder has a location method that can be used to get the user's ip address:

```
@userLocation = request.location #gets the ip of the user
@searchResults = Geocoder.search(search_locations)
@locations = @searchResults.near(@userLocation, 50, :order => :distance)
```

Comment: what is `search_locations`